# Is it normal for (fake) host in HTTP request header to recieve requests?

Tags: routing, http

Penetration testing has suggested our web app is vulnerable to server-side request forgery. The supposed proof is that when making a request with a fake Host header (example: `fakehost.com`) to our web app, we see incoming HTTP requests in `fakehost.com` logs. (`fakehost.com` could be controlled by an attacker) The behaviour happens once but then can't be reproduced for a given host.

```
curl -i -s -k -X $'GET' \
    -H $'Host: fakehost.com' -H $'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H $'Accept: */*' -H $'Accept-Language: en' -H $'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36' -H $'Connection: close' \
    $'https://subdomain.django_web_app.com/example'
```

Sending the above request once to our web app has generated six incoming requests on `fakehost.com`, two without a path and four with the path from the request. The requests come from three different IP addresses, two are from the country where the web app is hosted and one is from the country where I am -- can't recognise any of these IP addresses, they are not my own IP address or our servers and they are not in Amazon AWS IP ranges. (The web app is behind an Amazon AWS load balancer.)

**Are these requests made by the network along the way? Is this normal behaviour?**

Comment: More requests appearing on your logs makes me suspect there may be more to this then revealed by your `/example` path. Sure, your server should not respond to such requests in the first place, but what it does after processing them might still indicate a problem not obvious here, inside your application - not just its current deployment / proxy setup.

Comment: The headers as observed by your `curl` sample call might clarify this a bit.

Comment: Are you passing requests directly to your app without a web server in front of it?!

Comment: no, sry for confusion. it's a standard setup AWS load balancer -> EC2 -> nginx -> gunicorn -> Django

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, in fact it is so common to have such requests forwarded to your application that [Django documentation devotes a paragraph](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/security/#host-headers-virtual-hosting) just to discussing how to address common *seemingly-secure configurations*, explicitly warning

> in many common web servers a configuration that seems to validate the Host header may not in fact do so

The simplest most obvious such case is the attacker entirely bypassing your load balancer when your application backend is accessible without going through your proxy.

In any case, because it is so notoriously hard to get right on the proxy, it may be entirely acceptable to just point out that the access log not just logs these requests, but also logs that they have been correctly rejected with a `400` HTTP status code.

Remember your application is not vulnerable to that class of spoofing attacks just because it receives these requests. What would make it vulnerable would be acting on them in any fashion that might reveal or change state. **Your application should be correctly configured to validate the header and respond `HTTP 400` accordingly if receiving requests with unexpected hosts.**

Comment: Okay, but what I don't understand is that the load balancer is on AWS and fake host received requests from IPs that were not in the AWS published IP ranges (also one request was from my own location, not own IP though, which is different from where the web app and load balancer sit). Again, as the requester I sent a request to the web app not fake host, but something showed up there.

Comment: Well, did the request with the mismatching header even *use* your load balancer, or was it directly sent to your backend?

Comment: it goes through the load balancer like any request to the app would. As you write, the web app correctly responds with 400 status code, Django catches the invalid host.